# Linux on arm64: Mapping device registers to user space without using pgprot_noncached

Tags: linux, memory-alignment, arm64

We are working ARM64 based CPU and trying to map device address to user space in driver's mmap function.

We are currently using `pgprot_noncached` and `remap_pfn_range` for mapping device registers to user space, but this is giving:

```
unhandled alignment fault (7) at 0xffffb420f080
```

I referred [Linux on arm64: unhandled alignment faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093013/linux-on-arm64-sendto-causes-unhandled-fault-alignment-fault-0x96000021-wh#) , which indicates `pgprot_noncached` imposes strong ordering which is cause of issue.

I can't use solution mentioned in [Linux on arm64: unhandled alignment faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093013/linux-on-arm64-sendto-causes-unhandled-fault-alignment-fault-0x96000021-wh#), as dma_mmap_coherent expects dynamically allocated memory from `dma_zalloc_coherent`. Is there any other way to map device memory to user space without using DMA APIs